Is sub-d modeling a good workflow for low poly models with baked high poly details?
As a blender newbie I'm investigating the best way to create models for my game. I have tried low-poly character which is nice and have seen other methods like sculping.
Sculping is nice, you can work with more freedom compared to modeling but the problem is that you need to retopologize the mesh if you want to use the model in games.
Today I discovered sub-d modeling. It seems very nice because you can work on a very low poly model but keeping high level of detail. I have noticed you can convert the subd model to the base low poly mesh by reducing the subdivisions to 0. So, a question comes to mind. Are artists creating low poly models really using this workflow? The advantage I see is that I could have the low poly and the high poly version without any retopology and working with a bit of care the mesh is very easy to manipulate and in the end have: The low poly model, and a texture with all the details in a normal map for example.
Is this possible? I'm just missing something important?

This forum is not meant for questions with opinion-based answers, generally. With everything in game dev, the answer is "it depends". There are dozens of workflows for making literally any single thing in a game. I would recommend trying something and seeing what you like and don't like. Don't get hung up on picking the "correct workflow" just try a few out and see if they work for what you need. Watch tons of tutorials to get an idea of how other pro artists are working. I would recommend checking out Artstation Learning for insight into pro workflows.

I can only agree with Jakemoyo. If you feel one day somewhat limited in your creativity, then it will be the time to think about changing your workflow.
